# Upgrading to VS2017 broke Windows.Devices dependencies

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-2017

I upgraded to VS2017 and now I am no longer able to reference a few namespaces, like:

- using Windows.Devices.I2c;
- using Windows.Devices.Gpio;

I have checked universal windows extensions (10.0.14393) in project references.

I also tried copying the Extension SDK as explained [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19245/using-windowsdevicesi2c-not-recognized-after-upgra.html).

I still am not able to compile my .NET core app for neither ARM nor x86.

Is there a fix for this problem?

PS: my solution compiled and ran fine under VS2015...

Comment: Have you tried the official sample like [General Purpose Input/Output (GPIO) sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/IoT-GPIO)? Does it work in your side?  I've tested with VS2017 (15.0.26228.12) and it worked well.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Nope, also doesn't work. I installed universal app and core. Any ideas what I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4b08db8-2d51-4322-a330-8ee7b3f1fb48/visual-studio-2017-no-longer-able-to-compile-against-windowsdevicesgpio?forum=WindowsIoT) was deinstalling VS2017 and all Windows 10 SDKs, and installing VS2017 again from scratch.